# Retrieving Records Where User_ID Made a Transaction In December, but Not in January

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have the following table and I want to select each user_id who has made a transaction in December, but not in January.

```
    User_Id  |Month     |Transaction_Id   |Transaction_Amount 
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    1       |Dec        |50               |452.36   
    1       |Jan        |51               |963.2   
    3       |Dec        |52               |499.3   
    4       |Jan        |53               |156.85   
    1       |Dec        |54               |145.63   
    3       |Dec        |55               |20.99
```

The table should look like the following when the query has been executed:

```
User_Id  |Month     |Transaction_Id   |Transaction_Amount 
------------------------------------------------------------
3       |Dec        |52               |499.3       
3       |Dec        |55               |20.99
```

Note that I need to use an efficient query that filters for the requirements stated above since this will be applied to thousands of records.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I didn't know something like SQLFiddle existed. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few methods:

Using NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from yourtable t
where month = 'Dec'
and NOT EXISTS (
    select null from yourtable t2
    where t2.user_id = t.user_id
    and t2.month = 'Jan')
```

using NOT IN()

```
select * from yourtable t
where month = 'Dec'
and user_id NOT IN (
    select t2.user_id from yourtable t2
    where t2.month = 'Jan')
```

using LEFT JOIN:

```
select t.* from yourtable t
left join yourtable t2 on t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.month = 'Jan'
where t.month = 'Dec'
and t2.user_id IS NULL
```